# jythonc is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, python, jython

I've been trying to compile Jython `.py` files into Java `.class` files, yet whenever and wherever I try to run "`jythonc`". Here's how my environment variables are set:
`JYTHON_HOME` is set in where jython.jar is (the install directory)
`JYTHONPATH` is the install directory's bin folder
I'm using Jython 2.7.0 and Python 3.4.3.

Comment: jythonc has been retired. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763129/jythonc-missing

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that `jythonc` is not on the `PATH`.  You will need to set the `PATH` environment variable so that it contains the Jython `bin` folder.